# Easy Java Boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I need help with fixing my boolean, I am very new to programming and my professor's english is poor.

I need to add 5 to `mpg` if `highway` is `true` and subtract 2 when `city` is `false`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvancedTripCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // New Trip Calc.
        String firstname;
        int mpg;
        int miles;
        double price;
        double totalcost;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your First Name");
        firstname = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the MPG of your car");
        mpg = in.nextInt();
        boolean highway = true;
        boolean city = false;
        if (highway == true) {
            mpg = mpg + 5;
        }
        if (city == false) {
            mpg = mpg - 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter true if trip is on the highway false if the trip is       in the city");
        in.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Miles to be traveled");
        miles = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the price per gallon of gas");
        price = in.nextDouble();

        totalcost = miles * price / mpg;
        System.out.println("Your name is " + firstname);
        System.out.println("Your MPG is " + mpg);
        System.out.println("Your miles to be traveled is " + miles);
        System.out.println("Your price per gallon of gas is " + price);
        System.out.println("Your total cost is " + totalcost);
    }
}
```

Comment: the boolean as of now add 3 to the mpg, but i need it to add 5 if true or subtract 2 if false

Comment: Please start by at least properly formatting your code. Indentation matters; this stuff is really **hard** to read. You want others to help; so at least make their job as easy as possible.

Comment: No, it adds 5, and then substracts 2. Just like you specified. The conditions are not mutually exclusive. And the result is a change of +3.

Answer (score 2):

Make one boolean variable, for example, `boolean inCity;`

Change `in.nextBoolean();` to `inCity = in.nextBoolean();`

Then AFTER you have your input value you can check using the `if` statements. In your code, you check the `if` statement before you get the input.

So you would have this:

```
boolean inCity;
System.out.println("Are you in the city?(true/false): ");
inCity = in.nextBoolean(); //Store input in variable

if (inCity) { //If the condition is a boolean variable, you can type it like this(if (boolean) )
    mpg -= 2;//Same as mpg = mpg - 2;
} else { //if inCity is false:
    mpg += 5; //mpg = mpg + 5;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, mine is incomplete. The location of OP's if statements is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (highway) { 
    mpg = mpg + 5;
}

if (!city) {
    mpg = mpg - 2;
}
```

should be

```
if (highway) { 
    mpg = mpg + 5;
} else { //not highway, so city 
    mpg = mpg - 2;
}
```

Right now you check if its a highway. If it is `true` the code adds 5. Then you check if it is not a city. If it is `false` the code subtracts 2.

Also, you can only check the boolean after it has been submitted:

```
System.out.println("Enter true if trip is on the highway false if the trip is in the city");
boolean highway = in.nextBoolean();
if (highway) { 
    mpg = mpg + 5;
} else { //not highway, so city 
    mpg = mpg - 2;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I kept his formatting, but better show how to format also :)

Comment: the final solution just adds 5 to the mpg even if they enter false

Comment: Check the one below... This is not the only error in your code. My point was... if you need to check if someone is in a city or on a highway, you can do this with one boolean, since it has 2 values.

boolean highway = true; if highway == false then city

Comment: @Turing, thanx for the extra corrections, but maybe explain to the OP what's happening. if (highway == true) is not an incorrect statement.